# What is an easy-to-use JavaScript minifier for Ubuntu?

Tags: javascript, minify

What is an easy-to-use free JavaScript minifier running in Ubuntu?

It should be easy to install as well. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/)

Documentation: [Getting started](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app)

Comment: Note: This requires java

Answer (score 9):

I'm using the [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)

Comment: sudo apt-get install yui-compressor

Answer (score 4):

Check JSMin:

https://bitbucket.org/dcs/jsmin/

Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install jsmin
```

Usage as CLI:

```
python -m jsmin myfile.js
```

For example:

```
python -m jsmin large1.css large2.css > minified.css
```

As library:

```
from jsmin import jsmin
with open('myfile.js') as js_file:
    minified = jsmin(js_file.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using some Javascript task runners such as Grunt or Gulp, if you dont want to use any task runners, just install Node in your ubuntu by

```
git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Once the installation is complete

Just install a package called "minifier" via NPM ( node package manager )

```
npm install -g minifier
```

g in the above command is to make this package available globally throughout the system .

Once the installation is complete you can just run the below command to minify your javascript.

```
minify --output path/to/output/file path/to/inputfile
```

Some times using Google Closure compiler, creates lot of problem, Since it throws lot of compiler errors by checking against standards,But still it does a great job, sometimes we will not be in a position to fix those ECMA standard issues displayed by google closure. :)

Hope this post helps other folks who are facing similar issue.